# Moving an std::unordered_map values to std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Is there any way to **move** `unordered_map` values to a vector? All the ways I was able to find copy values (like in my example) instead of using something similar to `std::move`.

I would like to not copy values so I can retain uniqueness of `shared_ptr` foo, which I'll later change to `unique_ptr`.

```
class Class {
    public:
        std::shared_ptr <int> foo = std::shared_ptr <int> (new int (5));
};

int main() {
    std::unordered_map <int, Class> mapOfObjects({
                                                  {1, Class()},
                                                  {2, Class()},
                                                  {3, Class()},
                                                  {4, Class()},
                                                  {5, Class()} }); 
    std::vector <Class> someVector;

    for (auto &object : mapOfObjects) {

        someVector.push_back(object.second);
        std::cout << "Is unique?  " << ( someVector.back().foo.unique() ? "Yes." : "No.")                    
            << std::endl << std::endl;
    }  
}
```

Thank you in advance for all helpful answers.

Answer (score 7):

You can certainly move `shared_ptr` from `unordered_map` to `vector`. All you need to do is to use `std::move` in your example:

```
someVector.push_back(std::move(object.second));
```

Keep in mind, after this operation, you might want to clear the map, as it now contains empty objects.

Answer (score 4):

[@SergeyA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53268722/9593596) already covers the essential part here, let me nevertheless add a solution based on [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/), it shows where one part of the language is heading to with C++20.

```
#include <range/v3/view/map.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/move.hpp>

using namespace ranges;

/* Setup mapOfObjects... */

const std::vector<Class> someVector = mapOfObjects | view::values | view::move;
```

The STL in its current shape isn't that bad either, but admittetly more verbose:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::vector<Class> someVector;

std::transform(std::move_iterator(mapOfObjects.begin()),
        std::move_iterator(mapOfObjects.end()),
        std::back_inserter(someVector),
        [](std::pair<int, Class>&& entry){ return std::move(entry.second); });
```

Comment: Ranges are awesome.

Comment: How can I move elements from a map to a vector? Both containers have a different placement of elements in memory. So if it's not a shared_ptr - values will be copied anyway, right?